# A function to find or return a Google Calendar event Organizer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-app-maker, google-calendar-api

Is there a function in app script or app maker to get the organizer of a google calendar event? Currently my program is sorting jobs by creator, but the creator is not always the organizer so I was wondering if there is a field for organizer, or way to access that variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can get event organizer using [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).

```javascript
var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
console.log(event.organizer.email);
```

To add [Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings#add_advanced_services) in App Maker go to `App Settings -> Advanced Services section -> Add Service button`.

Comment: I tried what you said and I am getting an error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: Not Found

Comment: Works fine for me, when I pass valid `calendarId` and `eventId` and throws exactly the same exception when I pass invalid `eventId`. Where do you get `eventId` and `calendarId` values?

Comment: I am using an Event I get from an array made by "getEventsForDay()" and using  "Calendar.Events.get( Event.getOriginalCalendarId(), Event.getId());"

Comment: Strange... but `Calendar` (advanced service) and `CalendarApp` give `id` in different formats: `fancy_id` for advance and `fancy_id@google.com` for ordinary one. So, you can try to strip away `@google.com` suffix, but I would recommend to use one service for consistency.

Comment: So I am taking your advice and making all of my events using the advanced service, as with the regular calendar I was using the getEventsForDay(), I am trying to accomplish the same thing but there is no function like that in the advanced service, I am currently trying Calendar.Events.list(CalendarID, optional start/end time). How do I make an optional arg of 1 day?

Comment: Please, take a look at these docs: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: So I take an array of calendarIDs and I want to get an array of events for given day of all calendars owned by a user. I take the array of calendars and use it as my first parameter and create an object with the start/end times of 0:00:00-23.59.59 on the specified day, I enter in my function so it looks like this 'eventsArray = (Calendar.Events.list(calendarArray[x], {timeMax: startTime.toISOString(), timeMin: endTime.toISOString()}));' but this is giving my an empty array. Also the calendarIDs are my companies email address so is it ok they dont have @gmail.com at the end of the users?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list - says, that the first parameter is string, not an array of strings.

Comment: My first parameter is a string, I am just using an array to hold all the CalendarID strings of all the calendars a person has access to. So calendarArray[x] is in a loop so that it gets all the events for each calendar each time it runs the loop.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Normally, the events query will be executed on your behalf (unless you explicitly changed this AM project setting) and in theory you should be able to get all events for all calendars that you can view at calendar.google.com.